# Is it usual that Google Adsense displays the same Adverts multiple times on one page?

Tags: google, google-adsense, advertising

I have a Domain with two same-sized Leaderboards (728 x 90, Banners) and one Medium Rectangle (300 x 250, Block) on every Website. [This answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/19252/71270) says that

> if you place more than one ad unit on a page, our [Google Adsense's] system will display unique ads to each ad unit.

Unfortunately the two same-sized Leaderboards often show exactly the same advert. Is this only related to [personalized advertising](https://support.google.com/ads/answer/2662856?hl=de) or is this an issue of my code?

Comment: Perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this adbehavoir is connected to or based on [personalized advertising](https://support.google.com/ads/answer/2662856?hl=de).